# Increasing heap space for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ram

I am using Eclipse on 16.04 and for some programs it gives this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How do I increase the allocated heap space?

Comment: Is your question about increasing the heap space for Eclipse itself, or the programs you run through Eclipse?

Comment: Increasing the heap space.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381849/1039893 and I think it's off-topic mainly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to increase the heap space for the Eclipse itself look for the **eclipse.ini** file in your Eclipse installation directory and change the value `-Xmx1024m`. For example, you can increase the heap space on 2GB with `-Xmx2048m`.